# Boost HTTP server issue

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio

I'm starting to use Boost, so may be I'm messing something up.

I'm trying to set up http server with boost (ASIO). I've taken the code from docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html (HTTP Server, the first one)

The only difference from the example is I'm running server by my own method "run" and starting io_service in background thread, like in the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html

```
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service_);
```

(Also I'm stopping io_service from my run method too.)

When I'm starting this modified server everything seems to be OK, run method is working fine. But then I'm trying to get a doc from the server the request hangs and control flow never comes to "request_handle" method.
Am I missing something?

UPD. Here is my code of run method:

```
void NetstreamServer::run()
{
  LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(logger, "NetstreamServer is running");
  boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service_);
    try
    {
      while (true)
      {
        if (condition)
        {
          io_service_.stop();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
      LOG4CPLUS_ERROR(logger, "NetstreamServer" << " caught exception: " << e.what());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `io_service_.run()` ?

Comment: May be I'm misunderstanding the doc (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html), but AFAIU since I'm creating "work" object I do not need this.

Comment: Work object only ensures that `io_service::run` won't exit (quoting from your link: *"This ensures that the io_service object's run() function will not exit while work is underway, and that it does exit when there is no unfinished work remaining."*). But if you don't call `io_service::run`, no one will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`io_service_::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) - otherwise no one will dispatch the completion handlers of `Asio` objects serviced by `io_service_`.

Comment: I get this, but I have a question: does `work` object prevent `io_service::run` from blocking? Or what I need to do to get such behavior?

Comment: @Val No, `work` prolongs `run` blocking, because `run` blocks as long as it has any work. If you need non-blocking handler pumping, use `poll` (and you don't need `work` object; http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html). I really recommend you to read the Asio tutorial and to go through its reference, *before* writing applications.

Answer (score 0):

Without including the code you changed, everyone here can only guess. Unfortunately you also do not include the compiler and the OS you are using. Even with boost claiming it is platform independent, you should always include this information, as it reality, platforms are different even with boost.

Let me do a guess. You use Microsoft Windows? How do you prevent the "main" function to exit? You moved the blocking "run" function out of it in another thread, the main function has no wait point anymore. Let me guess again, you used something like "getchar". With that, you can exit your server with only hitting the keyboard return key. If yes, the problem is the getchar, with unfortunately blocks every io of the asio socket implementation, but only on Windows based systems.

I would not need to guess if you would include the informations mentioned in your post. In particular all(!) changes you made to the code sample.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using linux (Mint 14 x64 if it's matters), and I've updated my question adding code of run method. Hope it is clearer now.